# Exit option not function :(

Tags: python-3.x

Dear fellow python masters, please be nice with me, I'm just a newbie in python program. Right now I'm stuck with **'Exit'** option. Below is my code to calculate BMI. Any suggestion? Thanks so much :)

```
import os
import math

def menu():
    print('\tBMI Calculator')
    print('\t1. Metric Unit - kg and m')
    print('\t2. Exit - not function yet')
    inp = input('>> ')
    
def metric():
    inp1 = input('Enter your weight in kg: ')
    inp2 = input('Enter your height in m: ')

    weight = int(inp1)
    height = float(inp2)

    bmi = weight / (height * height)
    if bmi <= 18.5:
        print('You are underweight')
        print('{:.2f}'.format(bmi))

    elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi <= 24.9:
        print('You are in normal weight')
        print('{:.2f}'.format(bmi))

    elif bmi >= 25.0 and bmi <= 29.9:
        print('You are overweight')
        print('{:.2f}'.format(bmi))
    
    elif bmi  > 30.0:
        print('Obese')
        print('{:.2f}'.format(bmi))
    
    else:
        print('Wrong input')
    
    print('Keep continue consume healthy food!\n')

while True:
    menu()
    metric()
    os.system('pause')
    os.system('cls')
```

Comment: And...what do you want and what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `metric` function is run regardless of what you entered as a response in ```menu``.

Try the following:

```
def menu():
    print('\tBMI Calculator')
    print('\t1. Metric Unit - kg and m')
    print('\t2. Exit - not function yet')
    return input('>> ')
```

Then in the loop:

```
while True:
    resp = menu()
    if resp == "1":
        metric()
    else:
        break
os.system('pause')
os.system('cls')
```

That way, if the user selects 1, it runs the `metric()` function.  Otherwise, it quits the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `break` in the while loop depending on the returned value from `menu()`.

```py
def menu():
  ...
  ...
  return input('>>')
```

```py
if menu() == '1':
   metric()

else:
   break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a simple check. Instead of checking for `True`, you can check for `while menu() == '1'`. The while statement will call the `menu()` function and the `return`  from  `menu()` will provide the necessary input for the while to check. This will ensure you get into the loop only to process the metrics. If the value is anything other than `1`, the code will exit and end the program.

To make this work, you also need to make a small change to your menu() function.

```
def menu():
    print('\tBMI Calculator')
    print('\t1. Metric Unit - kg and m')
    print('\t2. Exit - not function yet')
    return input('>> ')

#your metrics() function will come here
def metric():
    ......

while menu() == '1':
    metric()
    os.system('pause')
    os.system('cls')
```